# VS2015 menus blank

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've installed VS Community 2015 and am having an issue. Whenever I try to create or open a file, I'm presented with a blank popup window that can't do anything. Here is how it looks:

[New Project Window](http://s26.postimg.org/tgir0z57d/newprojectdialogue.gif)

I didn't find anyone else with the problem when googling it for a while. I've tried the following:

- Reinstalling the software
- Booting into safe mode
- Repairing the software
- Changing the software configuration (adding C++ libraries, etc)
- Threatening and bribing my computer

The first time I tried installing it, my system crashed halfway through. I'm wondering if some files were partially written somewhere? I have no idea where to check aside from the installation directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. The same dialogue box afterwards looks like this instead:

[Fixed New Project Window](http://s26.postimg.org/ii7hisgm1/newprojectdialoguefixed.gif)

This looks much better and I'm now able to chug along on the tutorial happily. It seems I was on the right track before. It seems I was installing from a corrupt source. To fix it, I...

1. Throw the disc my school gave me in the trash.
2. Uninstall Visual Studio.
3. Navigate to and manually delete the folder it used to occupy. (ie, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0)
4. Download the software again from a different location.
5. Reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiarized with the IDE to program into Visual Studio?  The way you mention, it´s de DEFAULT behavior: you get a clean form to add controls there.

Why don´t you access some initial help to discover how to program in VS 2015?

Comment: The OP dialog is for a new project, not adding controls.  It's definitely not the default behavior for the new project dialog, there should be a list of projects in the dialog.